# Cannot start video player activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, video

I have a video in my `/res/raw/` folder and I would like to start it using the native video player of the device.

This is my code:

```
String packageName = this.getPackageName();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/raw/" + R.raw.my_video);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

When I trie to start the video it crashes and I get this error in LogCat:

> 09-16 15:05:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(23298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-16 15:05:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(23298): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

I tried `Uri.parse(String)` on a hosted mp4-file from a random webpage with the same result.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Issue is you are using wrong raw folder name.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/raw/" + R.raw.my_video);
```

Remove and use like this.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.my_video);
```

Comment: Apparently not the only issue - still not working :(

Comment: whether you added permission? android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Added the permission...nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try below code hope it will help you

```
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ packageName  + "/" + R.raw.my_video);

 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(intentUri, "video/mp4");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what is the extension of your video file ?

Comment: as per Shadow said add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  permission in manifest

Comment: It may be some video codec issue . Not able to find the related activity for that video . better to open that mp4 into VideoView

Answer (score 0):

you add `/raw` extra in your URI path , Please make it

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.my_video);
```

Comment: True, but it still does not work, after I removed it :(

Comment: please use video view , there may be intent issue as when i run on my device it give me activty not found exception,

Comment: so use video view or media player